# How to use regex expression in oracle sql query?

Tags: regex, oracle

In my location field I have :

```
"Location:
SOME PLACE

Additional Details:
DEFECT
"
```

Somehow I need this to take out the `"SOME PLACE"`. I have tried to understand how the `regexp_substr()` function works, but it is very different from my C# background and I keep getting weird results like nulls.

Normally I would have expected to do something like :

```
regexp_substr(LocationField, 'Location:(.*)\n') as "NewLocation"
```

And for it to cut out the part in parenthesis... but I was wrong. Any ideas?

**SOLUTION :**

```
regexp_replace(FIELD, 'Location:'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||'(.*).*$'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||'Additional Details:.*$', '\1', 1, 1, 'n' ) as "Location"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
regexp_replace(LocationField, 
               'location:'||chr(10)||'([^'||chr(10)||']*).*$', '\1', 
                1, 1, 'n' )
```

ie the regex string

```
location:\n([^\n]*).*$
```

but as oracle will not work with `\n` we splice in `chr(10)` in its place.

the `n` mode means that `.` will match the newline character (so `.*$` gets rid of everything after the newline following the SOME TEXT.

if location can have mulitple lines of text followed by Addition Details, you could use:

```
regexp_replace(LocationField, 
               'location:'||chr(10)||'(.*)'||chr(10)||'Additional.*$',  
               '\1', 1, 1, 'n' ) as "NewLocation"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me most in reaching the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11744.html) instead:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE( target, LocationField, 'Location:(.*)\n', '' ) as "NewLocation"
from your_table;
```

Should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm... you seem to have 4 parameters, and the link has 3? I tried with 3 omitting the target, because the LocationField is the target, and it returned to me the whole field...

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the regex in multi-line mode, which means populating the full signature of the REGEXP_SUBSTR() call:

```
select regexp_substr( locationField, '^([A-Z ]+)$', 1, 1, 'm')
from your_table
/
```

The `'m'` is a match parameter specifying multi-line mode.  This means `^` and `$` in the matching pattern are treated as `newline` boundaries rather than the start and end of the string.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm#i1239858).